# Spark filter pushdown with multiple values in subquery

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a small table `adm` with one column `x` that contains only 10 rows. Now I want to filter another table `big` that is partitioned by `y` with the values from `adm` using partition pruning.

While here

```
select * from big b 
where b.y = ( select max(a.x) from adm a)
```

the partition filter pushdown works, but unfortunately this:

```
select * from big b
where b.y IN (select a.x from adm a )
```

results in a broadcast join between `a` and `b`

How can the subquery be pushed down as a partition filter even when I use `IN`

Comment: your issue is in Spark or Hive?

Comment: Im using Spark to process the data. The tables are created in Hive. My issue is in Spark

Comment: I think, it is logical. if you use Max then  it will return single value dataframe which can be call as variable so there will be no join but in second case, you are using IN which will internally join your dataframe with all possible value of another dataframe since your second dataframe is very small in size spark will perform broadcast join to make is more optimised by default. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as it does the broadcast join, it will have to do a full table scan of `big` whereas if it would do a filter operation it would only have to read some of the partitions from `big`. So my question is how can i get Spark to do a filter operation instead of the broadcast join here

Comment: Dynamic Partition Pruning is what i am looking for. It was added in Spark 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the result of your subquery by itself is an RDD, so Spark deals with it in a truly distributed fashion -- via broadcast and join -- as it would if it were any other column, not necessarily partition.
To work around this, you will need to execute subquery separately, collect the result and format it into a value usable in `IN` clause.

```
scala> val ax = spark.sql("select a.x from adm a")
scala> val inclause = ax.as(Encoders.STRING).map(x => "'"+x+"'").collectAsList().asScala.mkString(",")
scala> spark.sql("select * from big b where b.y IN (" + inclause + ")")
```

(This assumes `x` and `y` are strings.)

Comment: Your approach works, but it is not what I am looking for. I want to be able to define the query in a view in Hive. The spark application should then only read from that view with the filters being pushed down. I thought there might be a config or a hint, to avoid the conversion of the IN to a broadcast join